# How to add :after and :before icon that change on click button dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html, css, icons, dropdown

With after and before I'm trying to change the dropdown icon when it is open or closed. So far I have not achieved any results, I am relatively new to all this and I do not understand how I can achieve the result, can someone help me please?

Actually I don't even know if that's the right way to do this.

**Edit**: Based on AStombaugh's answer I was able to get this result but I don't know if I'm doing it right. Can anyone give me explanations if what I am doing is right or wrong ? Sorry I'm new and trying to understand every aspect of js.

New snippet

```js
var dropdownBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.drop_btn');
iconDrop = null;
lastOpened = null; //Add this for toggling dropdown

dropdownBtn.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var dropCont = this.nextElementSibling;
  let icon = this.querySelector('.icon_item');
  icon.classList.toggle("visible");
  dropCont.classList.toggle("show");

  //Add this for toggling dropdown
  if (lastOpened && lastOpened !== dropCont)
    lastOpened.classList.remove("show");
  lastOpened = dropCont;

  if (iconDrop && iconDrop !== icon)
    iconDrop.classList.remove("visible");
  iconDrop = icon;
}));
```

```css
.drop_btn {
  background: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.icon_item:after {
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  content: '\f078';
  float: right;
}

.icon_item.visible:after {
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  content: '\f00d';
}

.drop_btn:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.drop_container {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

.drop_container.show {
  max-height: 300px;
  transition: max-height 0.3s ease-in;
}

.drop_container>.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css">

<div class="dropdown-menu">

  <div class="drop_btn">One<span class="icon_item"></span></div>
  <div class="drop_container">
    <a class="item" href="#">Contact Us</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Visit Us</a>
  </div>

  <div class="drop_btn">Two<span class="icon_item"></span></div>
  <div class="drop_container">
    <a class="item" href="#">Contact Us</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Visit Us</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Old original snippet

```js
var dropdownBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.drop_btn');
lastOpened = null; //Add this for toggling dropdown

dropdownBtn.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var dropCont = this.nextElementSibling;
  dropCont.classList.toggle("show");
  
  //Add this for toggling dropdown
  if (lastOpened && lastOpened !== dropCont)
      lastOpened.classList.remove("show");
      lastOpened = dropCont;
}));
```

```css
.drop_btn {
  background: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.drop_btn:before {
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  content: '\f077';
  float: right;
}

.drop_btn:after {
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  content: '\f078';
  float: right;
 }

.drop_btn:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.drop_container {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

.drop_container.show {
  max-height: 300px;
  transition: max-height 0.3s ease-in;
}

.drop_container > .item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css">

<div class="dropdown-menu">

<div class="drop_btn">One</div>
<div class="drop_container">
  <a class="item" href="#">Contact Us</a>
  <a class="item" href="#">Visit Us</a>
</div>

<div class="drop_btn">Two</div>
<div class="drop_container">
  <a class="item" href="#">Contact Us</a>
  <a class="item" href="#">Visit Us</a>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:before` and `:after` aren't doing what you think they're doing in this case. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before

However, you can actually treat Fontawesome icons as classes and then toggle them the same way you're handling the menu. See: https://fontawesome.bootstrapcheatsheets.com/ find the icon you want, copy the HTML tag, and then add the class to your CSS(everything in the `<i>` minus the `fa` part) and then manipulate them as you would any other CSS element. Add the actual HTML tag wherever you want the icon.

```js
var dropdownBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.drop_btn');
iconDrop = null;
lastOpened = null; //Add this for toggling dropdown

dropdownBtn.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var dropCont = this.nextElementSibling;
  let icon = this.querySelector('.fa-angle-up');
  icon.classList.toggle("down");
  dropCont.classList.toggle("show");

  //Add this for toggling dropdown
  if (lastOpened && lastOpened !== dropCont)
    lastOpened.classList.remove("show");
  lastOpened = dropCont;

  if (iconDrop && iconDrop !== icon)
    iconDrop.classList.remove("down");
  iconDrop = icon;
}));
```

```css
.drop_btn {
  background: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.fa-angle-up {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transform: rotateY(0);
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: 0.3s linear;
}

.fa-angle-up.down {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: 0.3s linear;
}

.drop_btn:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.drop_container {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

.drop_container.show {
  max-height: 300px;
  transition: max-height 0.3s ease-in;
}

.drop_container>.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css">

<div class="dropdown-menu">

  <div class="drop_btn">One<i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></div>
  <div class="drop_container">
    <a class="item" href="#">Contact Us</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Visit Us</a>
  </div>

  <div class="drop_btn">Two<i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></div>
  <div class="drop_container">
    <a class="item" href="#">Contact Us</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Visit Us</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. You are very kind. That was just what I was trying to do. Note that when you switch from one item to another the icon does not change state, but remains the same as the last time you clicked.

Comment: @Snorlax see update, you can use the same logic you used with the dropdown toggle on the icon too

Comment: Thank you again, it works great. Anyway, I'm trying to learn about js, so I was playing around with them a bit to find an alternative way and get the same result. Based on your answer I did this: https://jsfiddle.net/Snorlax93x/8ckpLmzo/2/ it works halfway, could you take a look at it ? In practice, the icon changes, but that of the div remains visible.

Comment: You might be able to do it like that but it seems like more hassle than it's worth since you'd have to find a way to toggle it and it seems like a counter-intuitive use of innerHTML anyway https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Comment: I understand, thanks. Then I'll just stick to your answer. However, what I was originally trying to do was not change the rotation of the icon, but show a completely different icon. Based on your answer, is it possible to change the icon instead of rotating it?

In this way, if in the future I have other different menus I will be able to manage the icons in a different way, changing them instead of rotating them. For example, I would like to show an X instead of a chevron rotated down.

Comment: You could use the `content` method like you had in your OP and just switch the content to a different icon but it might not play nicely with transitions. If you wanted to do something smooth like go from a chevron to an X, you'd need a bit more custom code to get it to look right

Comment: Actually I can do without the transitions on the icon. I'm fine with it even if it's not there. I try with css content and then update the post.

Comment: I managed somehow, I updated my question, if you like can you take a look at it and tell me if what I'm doing is right? Thank you so much.

Comment: Good job, seems like you figured it out!